# Telebot Неправильно работает условие

Tags: telebot

Бот должен здороваться с пользователем, когда входящие сообщение совпадает со значением из списка, но он просто пропускает это условие.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token') #Токен

# Ожидаем команду start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Привет, я Коннор - Телеграмм бот, не имеющий душу, но желающий стать живым. Поболтаем?")
    print(message)

#Список вариантов приветствия
list_hello=['Привет', 'При', 'Прив', 'Здравствуйте', 'Здравствуй', 'Здарова', 'Хэллоу', 'Хэлоу', "Хай"]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() in list_hello:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуй!')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'я тебя люблю':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADZgkAAnlc4gmfCor5YbYYRAI')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я вас не понимаю(')

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы проверяете так:

```py
if message.text.lower() in list_hello:
    ...
```

Это значит, если пользователь напишет "Привет", то `message.text.lower()` конвертирует его в "привет", и проверит есть ли оно в списке. Его нет :)

Самый просто вариант решения проблемы - перевести элементы в нижний регистр:

```py
list_hello=['привет', 'при', 'прив', 'здравствуйте', 'здравствуй', 'здарова', 'хэллоу', 'хэлоу', "хай"]
```